# Simplifying And of equality expressions

Tags: simplifying-expressions

This expression does not automatically simplify to `False`:

```
a == 0 && a != 0
```

`Simplify` and `Reduce` both do so however.

Is there a command that performs only this sort of simplification, without all the others that come along with `Simplify` and `Reduce`? I.e. it only looks for `And` expressions that have contradictions and simplifies them to `False`, leaving other expressions in the tree unchanged.

I'm curious what this simplification transformation step is called in computer-algebra systems in general. Perhaps something like *Logical Simplification*?

Comment: Either `BooleanMinimize` or `BooleanConvert` will evaluate to `False`.

Comment: Also `LogicalExpand` handles it.